# Localhost not working with fresh installation of Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, terminal, localhost, symfony-console

*I know there is a thread on it ("Symfony fresh installation is not working on my localhost") but the solution didnt helped me.*

I'm new to Symfony and I tried to create my first project. I installed a fresh copy of Symfony and then tried to start the server but I can't access localhost:8000, its loading forever and nothing happens.

My folder :

[Screen installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy9Zy.png)

I ran this command :
`php bin/console server:run`
It says everything is okay and I can now access it.

[Command Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsMp7.png)

..but when I try to access it, the tab is loading forever.

[Tab loading forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbHtL.png)

[Server status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo1hB.png)

I already tried to start the server on another port `php bin/console server:start *:8080` for example, but same problem happen. Am I doing something wrong ? Thanks for helping and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you installed a webserver to host the application on? Apache? NginX?

Comment: How did you create your Symfony project?  And why are you using localhost instead of something like: http://127.0.0.1:8000? Just copy the url from the server:run command.

Comment: I was just following a tutorial on how to create a new Symfony project and I had problem when going on the localhost adress (even when using the url from the server:run as @Cerad suggested). The problem was around my antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Reply,
Thanks to people answering this thread.

I found the solution. I removed my antivirus protection and now its working perfectly. I recently installed Avast and I tried to removed it and seems to be the problem. Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

On **Symfony 5 and Symfony 6** running on **Windows**:

You must stop de server, run this command in a terminal:

```
symfony server:stop
```

Then, run this command to start the server again:

```
symfony server:start
```

Sometimes when you run the command that stops the server, you may experience a permission error; you just have to run the server stop command again.